# How do I make titleless clauses appear in the scrjura table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, sections-paragraphs, scrjura

How do I make `\Clause`s without title appear in the table of contents?

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[contract,juratotoc]{scrjura}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\Clause{} % this one does not appear in the TOC
This is the text.

\Clause{title={Appears}} % this one does appear
This is the text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\Clause{title={}}`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[contract,juratotoc]{scrjura}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle% there is no \title given
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\Clause{title={}} % this one appears in TOC, too
This is the text.

\Clause{title={Appears}} % this one does appear
This is the text.
\end{document}
```

[image]